# Values of linear functional on open ball

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I have to show that for a continuous linear functional $T$ from a normed linear space space $X$ to a normed linear space $Y$, for all $x_0 \in X $ and $ r>0$, the following inequalities hold:
$$sup_{x\in B(x_0,r)}||Tx||\ge r ||T||_{L(X,Y)}$$

I have tried to make a proof just using triangular inequality, definitions and so on but it just does not work. Any hint is really appreciated.

Comment: Possible hint: it might be easier to relate the left side to the operator norm if we rewrite it as $\sup_{x \in B(0, r)}\|Tx+Tx_0\|$.

Comment: By the way, the term "linear functional" is typically reserved for linear maps from $X$ into your scalars.  Your $T$ is just a continuous linear map.

Comment: I'll add one more observation to the hint: you can use the triangle inequality to show that for any $a, b$, either $\|a\| \le \|a+b\|$ or $\|a\| \le \|-a+b\|$ (or both).  Do you see how to finish it from here?

Comment: That was exactly my attempt, I got stuck right there.

Comment: I've posted the full answer.  You can try only reading part of it as a hint and finishing on your own if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$.  By the definition of $\|T\|$, we can find an $x \in B(0, 1)$ with $\|Tx\| \ge \|T\|-\epsilon$.

Multiplying both sides by $r$, we have $\|T(rx)\| \ge r\|T\|-r\epsilon$.  Note $rx \in B(0, r)$.

Finally, using the hint and replacing $x$ with $-x$ if necessary, we may assume that $\|T(rx)+T(x_0)\| \ge \|T(rx)\|$.

So we have $\sup_{x\in B(x_0, r)}\|T(x)\| \ge \|T(rx)+T(x_0)\| \ge \|T(rx)\| \ge r\|T\|-r\epsilon$.

But $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, so taking $\epsilon\downarrow 0$, we get the desired inequality.